# Derivative of inverse function.

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = {1\over 27}(x^5 + 2x^3)$. Verify that $f$ has an inverse. Then use the function $f$ and the given real number $a$ to find ($f^{-1})'(-11)$. $a=-11$

I've gotten this far
${(x^5+2x^3)\over 27}=-11$

then,

$x^5+2x^3=-297$

From here, I'm not sure how to proceed, as I've tried to do it with algebra, but kept getting road blocked.

I looked online for some explanation, but the only explanations I've found, in regards to this problem, promote guessing the corresponding value of the inverse, $f^{-1}(-11)=-3$.

The reason I question the "guessing method" is because of the fact that the corresponding inverse might be a fraction, and it would almost be very hard to guess.

Comment: What is your given number $a$? And it seems that you haven't find the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Any polynomial of degree $5$ or more cannot be solved by radicals. This is a classical result due to Abel and derives from the fundamental theorem of Galois Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

To show $f$ has an inverse, try to show $f$ is one to one and onto. To show this in our case, try to show $f$ is monotone. Now, how do you show $f$ is monotone?

Hint 2:

What is the relationship between the derivative of a function at a point and the derivative of its inverse? More specificlly, if $f\circ g=1, g\circ f=1$, what can you say about the relationship between $f'$ and $g'$?

Comment: I'm mainly asking about the computational aspect of the question. I get inverses of functions, I just don't know how to get the specific answer in this case.

Comment: But I cannot just do it for you. The computational side is easy once you get the concepts.

Comment: Are you suggesting factoring a 5th degree polynomial? If so, wouldn't that be a messy process every time I do a problem like this?

Comment: @PeaktoPeak: Clearly, you did not get my first hint. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider it at first. But you have a point (I did some quick research). The reason why I didn't consider your first hint was because in my textbook, in the "Derivatives of Inverse Functions", the concept of what a Monotonic Function is not introduced.

Comment: @PeaktoPeak: Did you get it now? I hope it is not too difficult.